# gui miner wont mine on slushes pool

Tags: miner-configuration, guiminer

I want to ask a question that why isn't GUI miner working this is what is said

in the bottom right corner it says connecting... but nothing happens 
I am very new and don't know about mining so much and this is the first time I am trying 
help me I am on windows 8

Answer (score 1):

Read the manual for gui-miner and make sure have the connection parameters configured correctly. Mining is super competitive these days so unless you have a high-end computer which can output high hash-rates you will very likely wait a long time for coins. In the meantime you are burning electricity which you or someone else need to pay for.